# openlayers vectors and stringline

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have an array of point which I change to LineStrings - > it seems like curved line, and I want my Marker (Vector) go along this path with correct angle (rotate on curves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate the angle between 2 points (preceding and following your marker on the linestring) : p1, p2:

```
var dx = p2.x-p1.x;
var dy = p2.y-p1.y;
var angle = Math.atan2(dx,dy);
var degrees = 360-(angle*180/Math.PI)-90;
```

Then make a rotation with "degrees" parameter: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/styles-rotation.html